# How to skip the features select screen in WIX-generated installer program?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix-gui

I want the installer to skip showing setup type screen (where you can choose Typical, Custom, Complete features), How can I do this?
I provided only one feature set named product.
And I also want the user be able to change the installation directory.

Comment: I changed from WixUI_Mondo to WixUI_InstallDir. And it worked.
Note: you have to add a <property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" ... />, or you will get a 2189 error when setting up. Check the document of WIXUI_INSTALLDIR for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My application only has a licence screen then installation directory screen, and I use this configuration block to-do it:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="License.rtf" />
```

just before the end of my `</Product>` tag. All the application installs into `INSTALLLOCATION` in the `<Directory>` section.

The [WixUI dialog library guide](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) might help explain the options

Answer (score 5):

If you only require the user to customize the installation folder, use:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

If you don't permit customization of the installation folder, use:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
```

Chances are you're using one of the built in libraries that *does* include the Feature Tree selction, i.e.

- WixUI_Mondo
- WixUI_FeatureTree
- WixUI_Advanced

Comment: hi, i dont want to provide feature screen (i.e. typical,custom and complete) and i have created some custom dialogues those are required to show up so i think i cant use WixUI_Mondo. if i am using WixUI_Advanced then it gives me error 
"Error 1 Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_Advance' in section 'Fragment:'. D:\Projects\WixDemoWPFAppVS2012\WixDemoWPFAppVS2012\WixDemoWPFAppVS2012\Setup\WixDemoWPFAppVS2012.Setup\GUI.wxs 41 1 WixDemoWPFAppVS2012.Setup"
i am confused here